# Confusion with Hashes and Arrays when using steam-condenser Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, steam-condenser

I'm trying to use the steam-condenser gem to pull a list of games for a particular user (myself). So far I have the following:

```rb
require 'steam-condenser'

id = SteamId.new 'tamachan87'
games_owned = id.games
```

`games_owned` is now a hash, containing keys and arrays.

If I call `games_owned.values` in IRB I will get a result that contains all the information of those games, from it's ID number to the name to its logo hash.

However, when I use the following:

```rb
games_owned.each do |key, array|
    puts "==== #{key} ===="
    puts array
end
```

I get just the first value of the array such as:

```rb
==== 200260 ====
#<SteamGame:0x00000100beb0a8>
```

Each value/array thing has an `@name` variable which is the only thing I want to pull.

Could someone please help me to better understand these hashes and how I can pull specific data (`@name`) from them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `p array` instead of `puts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `SteamId#games` is not a hash of arrays, it's a hash of `SteamGame` objects.

Your example code could be written like that:

```
games_owned.each do |app_id, game|
  puts "==== #{app_id} ===="
  puts game.name
end
```

See the [documentation of SteamId](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/steam-condenser/SteamId#games-instance_method) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get an unfriendly class name and memory value is that the `SteamGame` class does not define an `inspect` method. However if all you're interested is printing the names of the games, use `puts key.name`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print your Steamgame object in a pretty way by using "puts"
you should overwrite "to_s" in your Steamgame class.

The reason you are getting different results is puts uses to_s method to print its argument (which is
steamgame object itself in your case with specific id). 
If you use "p" or "puts array.inspect" instead of "puts", it will debug your object and you will see irb like results.

If you have an attribute like @name in your Steamgame class, you should be able to get it just by saying:
games_owned.values[i].name or puts array.name. 
did you try that?